# Webpack Does Not Recognise Babel Loader Even when babel loader is installed

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have webpack and babel loader installed, however, webpack is unable to recognise that Babel Loader is installed:

I installed babel loader and the presets using the following command: npm install @babel/core babel-loader @babel/preset-react --save-dev

Here is my

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'main.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}


module.exports = config
```

and package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "webpack",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "webpack --mode=development",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "npm": "^8.13.2",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Webpacks Babel module rule object has a wrong structure. Please, follow the Webpack [official docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/) and wrap your 'loader' and 'options' properties in a 'use'.

Wrong rules:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

Correct rules:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.m?js$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```